# Android checkbox checked in one activity and then button appears in another activity

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-button

The question says it all. Imagine there are 2 activity's, 'Activity A' and 'Activity B'.'Activity A' holds a checkbox when its checked a button should show on 'Activity B' when its unchecked the button should hide on 'Activity B'

below is the main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private BubblesManager bubblesManager;
    private boolean isCheckedValue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeBubblesManager();


        final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addNewBubble();
                add.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.add_fb);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                isCheckedValue = isChecked;

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
                intent.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );


            }
        });



    }
 private void addNewBubble() {
        BubbleLayout bubbleView = (BubbleLayout)LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout, null);
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleRemoveListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleRemoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBubbleRemoved(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleClickListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBubbleClick(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        bubbleView.setShouldStickToWall(true);
        bubblesManager.addBubble(bubbleView, 60, 20);
    }
```

Below is the next activity aka 'activity B'

```
public class PopUpWindow extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up_window);


    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));

    Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("yourBoolName",false);
    Button fbbutton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fbbutton1);
    if(yourBool){
            //For Displaying Button
        fbbutton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}
```

Below is the XML code for the button I want show when checkbox is clicked

```
<Button
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/fbbutton1"
        android:onClick="button"
        android:background="@drawable/fbcircle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Comment: i can't see any problem related with code, it possible that you did some changes in the code and your studio just gave you a old version of your project , try clean and Run or clean project and run your app

Comment: @PavneetSingh bro, there is no error in the app. the checkbox thing is not working even if the checkbox in 'Activity A' is not clicked the button in the 'Activity B' appears i dont no whats gone wrong

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. You are storing `yourBoolName` value in one `intent` and starting your activity with another `intent`. Of course it'll not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private BubblesManager bubblesManager;
private boolean isCheckedValue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeBubblesManager();


    final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addNewBubble();
            add.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.add_fb);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            isCheckedValue = isChecked;
// un-comment this code if you want to go to second activity when check change 
//
//                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
//                intent.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );
//  startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
 private void addNewBubble() {
        BubbleLayout bubbleView = (BubbleLayout)LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout, null);
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleRemoveListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleRemoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBubbleRemoved(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleClickListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBubbleClick(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
            in.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        bubbleView.setShouldStickToWall(true);
        bubblesManager.addBubble(bubbleView, 60, 20);
    }
}


   public class PopUpWindow extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up_window);


DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;

getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));

Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("yourBoolName",false);
Button fbbutton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fbbutton1);
if(yourBool){
        //For Displaying Button
    fbbutton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: bro, I even tried this logic earlier but it didn't really work.Since you have uploaded I tried but still the thing didn't work right. the problem is small but i dont no where it is @PavneetSighn  and I added android:visibility="gone" in xml would it have affected the code?

Comment: tell me what is the current behavior of your code and what is wrong with it

Comment: bro, I just did what you said updated the old code with the new one and the current behavior is even if the checkbox is checked or not the button is shown @PavneetSingh

Comment: are you starting your activity B from somewhere else too except from checkboxchange listner

Comment: when and from where you want to start activity B

Comment: bro, I'm also opening 'Activity B' through addNewBubble(); (I have declared the intent to open 'Activity B' in other part of the code) and Now i have added addNewBubble(); code part in the above program  @PavneetSingh

Comment: bro, where you able to find the mistake i did?? or i could mail you the code if necessary @PavneetSingh

Comment: i basically gave you solution to start activity from checkbox listener but later you said you are starting activity from somewhere else too and that code wasn't there before . the problem is very tiny so to solve it quickly `you just need to tell what is you want and what is the behavior of  current code and make sure the updated code is there which is relevant to problem`.tell me these things

Comment: try the updated code and if any problem then answer questions in the previous comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120984/discussion-between-pavneet-singh-and-gladwin-james).

Comment: Ok First Thankyou for being soo supportive, and now
for explanation.There is a Icon in Main Activity which when pressed should display an activity('id:add' dos this job and new activity name is PopUpwindow),and then there is bunch(having 1 for trail) of checkboxes(in Main Activity) when each check boxes is checked corresponding buttons should appear in Popwindow  activity   @PavneetSingh

Answer (score 3):

send boolean value with intent bundle in activity B. if it is true show button or hide it.

```
 //global value
    private boolean isCheckedValue;


    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    isCheckedValue = isChecked; //first set value then assign to boolean extra.

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
            intent.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );
            startActivity(intent);



                }
            });
        }
```

send with intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AcitivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );
startActivity(intent)
```

handle that on Acitivity B

```
Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("yourBoolName");

if(yourBool){
//display button
}
else{
//hide button
}
```

Comment: I just edited the complete code and updated above can yo please check it once, because there is an error in changes i did

Comment: you are setting isCheckvalue to bundle and then setting value to it . see my updated answer . @GladwinJames

Comment: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.txusballesteros.bubbles/com.txusballesteros.bubbles.PopUpWindow}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 '    bro still this error isthere :'(    @KDeogharkar

Comment: Thankyou for the support brother with your help only I found the error and solution for it Thankyou :) for the support

Comment: can you please chk the code because its not working as expected  @KDeogharkar

Comment: Is the code i Wrote in 'Activity B' to handle the checkbox is correct @KDeogharkar

Answer (score 1):

Change your Activity 'A' Like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private BubblesManager bubblesManager;
private boolean isCheckedValue;
private Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeBubblesManager();


    final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addNewBubble();
            add.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.add_fb);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener  (newCompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            isCheckedValue = isChecked;


            intent.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );


        }
    });



}
  private void addNewBubble() {
    BubbleLayout bubbleView = (BubbleLayout)LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout, null);
    bubbleView.setOnBubbleRemoveListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleRemoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBubbleRemoved(BubbleLayout bubble) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    bubbleView.setOnBubbleClickListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBubbleClick(BubbleLayout bubble) {

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    bubbleView.setShouldStickToWall(true);
    bubblesManager.addBubble(bubbleView, 60, 20);
}
```

And get bundle extra value in Activity 'B'

```
 boolean checkedStatus= getIntent().getBooleanExtra("yourBoolName",false);
 if(checkedStatus){
  // Do your job here
 }else{
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean isChecked of 'Activity A' in that save state of checkbox, pass it on 'Activity B', By using that boolean set visibility to your view in 'Activity B'.

Comment: I just edited the complete code and updated above can yo please check it once, because there is an error in changes i did @Hardik Kubavat

Comment: assign value to variable before passing it to another activity."isCheckedValue = isChecked;" before your calling Intent.